# Xml does not convert correctly to Object

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML input:

```
<Response xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Status>Ok</Status></Response>
```

I am trying to convert it to an object by:

```
XmlDocument xmlNode = new XmlDocument();
xmlNode.LoadXml(responseContent);
string jsonNode = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlNode);
var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationResponse>(jsonNode);
```

where `responseContent` is the above XML string. However, instead of getting

```
{Status: "Ok"}
```

I am getting:

```
{Status: null}
```

**Any idea why and how to correct it?**

Comment: Could you show `jsonNode` value?

Comment: You probably have a namespace issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to omit `RootObject`

```
XmlDocument xmlNode = new XmlDocument();
xmlNode.LoadXml("<Response xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Status>Ok</Status></Response>");
string jsonNode = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlNode, Formatting.Indented, true);
Console.WriteLine(jsonNode);

var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationResponse>(jsonNode);
Console.WriteLine(responseModel.Status);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to `string jsonNode = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlNode.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Status"));`

```
        XmlDocument xmlNode = new XmlDocument();
        xmlNode.LoadXml("<Response xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Status>Ok</Status></Response>");
        string jsonNode = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlNode.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Status"));

        var responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationResponse>(jsonNode);
```